# SVG fill not changing, not sure how to resolve it with multiple layers and paths

Tags: svg, fill

Apologies, I've seen that this has been asked a few times, but I can't quite figure out how to do it with multiple paths.

This is my SVG, I'd like it to still be white, but on hover it'd be nice to be able to have the colour change. If someone figures it out I'd really appreciate seeing the steps involved. Thanks.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Lager_2" data-name="Lager 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1702 1390.57">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        clip-path: url(#clippath);
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: none;
      }

      .cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4 {
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }

      .cls-5 {
        opacity: .95;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        fill: #fff;
      }
    </style>
    <clipPath id="clippath">
      <rect class="cls-2" width="1702" height="1390.57"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <g id="Lager_1-2" data-name="Lager 1">
    <g>
      <g class="cls-5">
        <g class="cls-1">
          <path class="cls-4" d="m1529.36,150.92c98.19,66.23,160.76,173.67,169.9,291.75,7.17,92.59.25,185.73-20.51,276.24-35.89,155.9-109.41,300.64-214.14,421.57-60.76,70.48-135.79,127.26-220.12,166.58-254.19,118.53-549.35,110.5-796.71-21.68-127.32-68.03-233.06-170.34-305.26-295.34C70.12,865.25,23.45,727.22,5.25,584.1c-6.94-54.85-7-110.35-.17-165.21,12.78-102.62,69.48-194.64,155.4-252.19,99.88-66.91,212.48-112.51,330.77-133.96,252.08-45.7,510.52-43.53,761.8,6.42,91.68,18.22,179.45,52.37,259.34,100.9,5.74,3.49,11.4,7.11,16.97,10.87"/>
        </g>
      </g>
      <g>
        <path class="cls-3" d="m433.89,484.59h101.07c44.59,0,78.12,6.68,100.59,20.02,22.46,13.35,33.69,36.05,33.69,68.12,0,13.84-2.65,26.25-7.93,37.23-5.29,10.99-12.98,20.06-23.07,27.22-10.09,7.16-22.54,12.13-37.35,14.89v2.44c15.62,2.44,29.46,6.92,41.5,13.43,12.04,6.51,21.48,15.62,28.32,27.34s10.25,26.61,10.25,44.68c0,21.97-5.09,40.53-15.26,55.66-10.17,15.14-24.54,26.57-43.09,34.3-18.55,7.73-40.53,11.6-65.92,11.6h-122.8v-356.93Zm41.5,153.08h68.36c31.09,0,52.61-5.13,64.58-15.38s17.94-25.23,17.94-44.92-7.12-34.99-21.36-43.95c-14.24-8.95-36.91-13.43-67.99-13.43h-61.52v117.68Zm0,34.91v133.55h74.22c31.74,0,54.2-6.23,67.38-18.68s19.78-29.25,19.78-50.42c0-13.51-2.97-25.06-8.91-34.67-5.94-9.6-15.54-16.97-28.81-22.09-13.27-5.13-30.97-7.69-53.1-7.69h-70.56Z"/>
        <path class="cls-3" d="m966.6,841.53h-233.89v-33.94l95.46-96.92c17.74-17.9,32.67-33.85,44.8-47.85,12.12-14,21.36-27.79,27.71-41.38,6.35-13.59,9.52-28.52,9.52-44.8,0-20.18-5.98-35.6-17.94-46.26-11.96-10.66-27.71-15.99-47.24-15.99-17.09,0-32.23,2.93-45.41,8.79s-26.7,14.16-40.53,24.9l-21.73-27.34c9.44-7.97,19.73-15.05,30.88-21.24,11.15-6.18,23.11-11.07,35.89-14.65,12.78-3.58,26.41-5.37,40.89-5.37,21.97,0,40.93,3.83,56.88,11.47,15.95,7.65,28.28,18.55,36.99,32.71,8.71,14.16,13.06,31.01,13.06,50.54s-3.75,36.42-11.23,52.61c-7.49,16.2-17.99,32.23-31.49,48.1-13.51,15.87-29.3,32.68-47.36,50.42l-77.64,77.39v1.71h182.37v37.11Z"/>
        <path class="cls-3" d="m1042.77,484.59h101.07c44.59,0,78.12,6.68,100.59,20.02,22.46,13.35,33.69,36.05,33.69,68.12,0,13.84-2.65,26.25-7.93,37.23-5.29,10.99-12.98,20.06-23.07,27.22-10.09,7.16-22.54,12.13-37.35,14.89v2.44c15.62,2.44,29.46,6.92,41.5,13.43,12.04,6.51,21.48,15.62,28.32,27.34s10.25,26.61,10.25,44.68c0,21.97-5.09,40.53-15.26,55.66-10.17,15.14-24.54,26.57-43.09,34.3-18.55,7.73-40.53,11.6-65.92,11.6h-122.8v-356.93Zm41.5,153.08h68.36c31.09,0,52.61-5.13,64.58-15.38s17.94-25.23,17.94-44.92-7.12-34.99-21.36-43.95c-14.24-8.95-36.91-13.43-67.99-13.43h-61.52v117.68Zm0,34.91v133.55h74.22c31.74,0,54.2-6.23,67.38-18.68s19.78-29.25,19.78-50.42c0-13.51-2.97-25.06-8.91-34.67-5.94-9.6-15.54-16.97-28.81-22.09-13.27-5.13-30.97-7.69-53.1-7.69h-70.56Z"/>
      </g>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've tried putting it in a SVG tag in the jsx file, however I can't quite figure it out when there are multiple layers and paths.

Comment: Not very sure what you are aiming for. Try `.cls-4:hover{fill:red}` - for example

Comment: @enxaneta Unfortunately that doesn't work.